# Proving inequality $\frac{2a}{3a^2+b^2+2ac} +\frac{2b}{3b^2+c^2+2ab}+\frac{2c}{3c^2+a^2+2bc}\le\frac{3}{a+b+c}$

Tags: inequality

$a,b,c$ are real positive numbers ,what is the proof that :

$$\frac{2a}{3a^2+b^2+2ac} +\frac{2b}{3b^2+c^2+2ab}+\frac{2c}{3c^2+a^2+2bc}\le\frac{3}{a+b+c}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Prove that
$$
\frac{2a}{3a^2+b^2+2ac}\leq\frac{1}{a+b+c}
$$

Comment: Additional hint if OP is unsatisfied:  Note that $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$ since squares are always positive, that is $0\leq (a-b)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I just follow the very good hint from Norbert's answer

$$\frac{2 a}{3 a^{2}+b^{2}+2 a c} \leq \frac{1}{a+b+c}$$
Since $a, b, c$ are real positive numbers, $2 a, 2 b, 2 c$ and $(a+b+c)$ are also real positive numbers
$$2 a(a+b+c) \leq 3 a^{2}+b^{2}+2 a c\\
2 a^{2}+2 a b+2 a c \leq 3 a^{2}+b^{2}+2 a c \\
2 a b \leq a^{2}+b^{2}\\
a^{2}+b^{2}-2 a b \geq 0\\
(a-b)^{2} \geq 0 $$ This is always true, thus $$\frac{2 a}{3 a^{2}+b^{2}+2 a c} \leq \frac{1}{a+b+c}$$
Similarly, we have $$\frac{2 b}{3 b^{2}+c^{2}+2 a b} \leq \frac{1}{a+b+c}$$
and $$\frac{2 c}{3 c^{2}+a^{2}+2 b c} \leq \frac{1}{a+b+c}$$
Therefore $$\frac{2 a}{3 a^{2}+b^{2}+2 a c}+\frac{2 b}{3 b^{2}+c^{2}+2 a b}+\frac{2 c}{3 c^{2}+a^{2}+2 b c} \leq \frac{3}{a+b+c}$$

Comment: Apart from the fact that you wrote the proof backwards without saying so (instead of the ususal "we know X therefore Y and we can conclude Z" your proof should read "we want to prove Z which will follow if Y for which it will suffice that X which is true), it is also unusual to post jour answer as jpeg file.

Comment: Sorry about posting my answer as jpg file. I am a new user of this website. I had been trying to write equations in my post, but I didn't know how to, hence I had to write in MS Word then captured it.

Comment: Here you can find [complete faq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) on writing formulas. And please, don't post complete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{3a^2+b^2+2ac}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{2a^2+a^2+b^2+2ac}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{2a^2+2ab+2ac}=\frac{3}{a+b+c}$$